# C++ member vs non-member operator+

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I saw 2 different approaches for implementing `operator+`.

In the standard library, `std::complex`, `operator+` is implemented as non-member function. In `Vector2` class used at work `operator+`is implemented as member function. As far as I know there is no conceptual difference between `std::complex` and `Vector2` regarding addition.

Is there any reason to not use the standard library approach when implementing `Vector2` class?  Is some real advantage to use one approach or the other or is just a matter of personal preference?

Note: `x` and `y` members from `Vector2` are public

Comment: Another big advantage of using free `operator+` is that you can use this syntax for every single class: `T operator+(T a, T const &b) { return a += b; }`, if you implement `operator+=` properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a very strong reason for it to be a non-member function: symmetry between LHS and RHS of an `+` expression. In the case of `std::complex`, it is implicitly convertible from a scalar type (`int`, `double` etc), so the following would not work if the operator were a member:

```
std::complex<double> c1;
std::complex c2<double> = 5.0 + c1;
```

whereas the following would:

```
std::complex c2<double> = c1 + 5.0;
```

That inconsistency wouldn't make much sense. A non-member binary operator allows the implicit conversions to take place.

**Note**: In my experience with mathematical vector types, it is often desirable to provide arithmetic operators involving other vector types:

```
template <typename V>
Vector2 operator+(const Vector2& lhs, const V& rhs)
{
  Vector2 ret = lhs;
  ret += rhs;  // uses member function template operator +=(const V&)
  return ret;
}

template <typename V>
Vector2 operator+(const V& lhs, const Vector2& rhs)
{
  return rhs + lhs;
}
```

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl Thanks. It was a typo. I meant `ret += rhs`. I don't take by value because it kills return value optimization. I am actually writing a short blog post about that at the moment.

Comment: it does? Guess you already got a reader for your blog post, it's the one in your profile, right? Because the last post was quite a while ago alread.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl It does. I haven't posted for a long time, but I hope to post the RVO-related one soon. It is not about *why* RVO is inhibited, but just showing some results with different implementations of `operator+`.